# Confusing normal map bake

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking, normal-map

I've been trying to bake a normal map to a low poly model from a tree trunk that I've photoscanned. But for some reason the normals appear to be at a weird angle... I'd expect the flat parts of the bark to be blue, facing forward, but instead they're red, making them reflect the light at an odd angle in the model.

Any idea what could be wrong?

[image]

Edit: Here's a correct normal map I was able to get out of another software called xNormal. I feel like I must be missing something in the setup?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally figured it out. I had to go into the object data and click clear split normals. I guess the photogrammetry software applied their own normal smoothing somehow